# Application not import in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I try to android application in android studio. But it freezes on below screen.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
Settings-->Build,Execution,Deployment-->Build Tools-->Gradle-->Offline work

Comment: is it problem in gradle version ?. my android studio version is 2.0, gradle version 2.10, android plugin version 2.0.0. and I checked project file manually, it has "classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0' " and gradle-2.14.1-all.zip.

Comment: i think it doesn't matters.my studio version is 2.1.1,build tools version is 2.2.0,gradle version is 2.14.1-all,and it works well.